# Pinterest effect with Masonry in div gets broken

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to use jQuery Masonry with Bootstrap 3 in a Django app, but I'm not getting the results expeted. Everytime the height of a picture is larger than the others in the column, it happnes like in the picture:

[image]

This is my code:

```
  <script src={% static "js/jquery.masonry.min.js" %}></script>


    <script>
  $(function(){

  var $container = $('#container');

  $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $container.masonry({
      itemSelector : '.item'
    });
  });

  });
</script>
```

And HTML

```
<div class="container">


 {% for key, values in prodmatrix %}
 <div class = "span3 item"> 

 <div class="product-box feed masonryImage">
 <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{values.1.0}}" />
 <a href="{% url 'product_detail' slug=values.3.0 %}" class="title">{{ values.0.0 }}</a><br/>
 <p>
 {{ values.0.0 }}
 </p>
 </div>

 </div> 
 {% endfor %}

 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the outermost div should contain the `class = "item masonryImage"`
In your case i.e that div containing class span3.